# Particular solution of the SOD $D^2y + 6 Dy + 10y = 2 \sin{2x}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> How can we find the particular solution to the following D.E?
>
> $$\frac{\text{d}^2y}{\text{d}x^2} + 6 \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} + 10y = 2 \sin{2x} \text{ —— (I)} $$
>
> $\text{ at } x = 0, y = \frac{5}{2} \text{——} $ provided $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} = \frac{1}{2}$.

---

Recall that the equations with the form $y'' + P_1y' + P_2y = 0$ are called linear SOD with constant coefficients, where $P_1$ and $P_2$ are constants.

The cited problem is partially identical to the differential equations with constant coefficients, except the RHS is nonzero. In my attempt, taking the trial solution $y = e^{mx}$, we have:

$$Dy = m \cdot e^{mx} \text{ and } D^2y = m^2 \cdot e^{mx}$$

Now, substituting it in (I), we have:

$$e^{mx} (m^2 + 6m + 10) = 2 \sin{2x}$$

We have either $e^{mx} = 2\sin{2x}$ or $m^2 + 6m + 10 = 2\sin{2x}.$

---

**The problem is that I have no idea how to proceed next because:**

1. $e^{mx}$ might not be ignored since RHS is nonzero.
2. $m^2 + 6m + 10$ cannot be factorized. Using the quadratic formula, we have $m = −3 \pm i$. Let these values be $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively.

   When $m$ is a conjugate complex quantities, we define the solution to such ODEs as: $y = Ae^{\alpha x} \cos{(\beta x + B)}$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the solutions.

Comment: You first solve the homogeneous equation for the complementary solution. Then guess or compute one particular solution for the inhomogeneous equation. The sum of both is then the general solution.

Comment: $e^{mx}$ is a wrong trial solution. Instead, $A\sin2x+B\cos2x$, with $A,B$ to be determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the particular solution $y_p(x)$ of the ODE we proceed as follows.

If $$(D^2+6D+10)y_p=2\sin ax \implies y_p= \frac{2\sin 2x}{-2^2+6D+10}=\frac{1}{3} \frac{\sin 2x}{D+1}$$ $$\implies y_p=\frac{1}{3} \frac{D-1}{D^2-1}\sin 2x$$
$$\implies y_p=\frac{1}{3} \frac{D-1}{-2^2-1}\sin 2x=-\frac{1}{15} (D-1)\sin 2x=-\frac{1}{15} (2\cos 2x- \sin 2x)$$

One may check that it satisfies the ODE.

**Edit**

Now find the general by putting $y=e^{mx}$ in the homogeneous eq.
$$y''+6y'+10y=0 \implies m^2+6m+10=0 \implies m=-3\pm i$$
This gives the general solution $$y_g(x)=e^{-3x}(P \sin x+ Q\cos x)$$
Now the total solution $$y=e^{-3x}(P\sin x+ Q \cos x)-(1/15)(2\cos 2x -\sin 2x)$$ needs to satisfy the given conditions to determine the values of $P$ and $Q$. Finally. by imposing $y(0)=5/2, y'(0)=1/2$, we get $p=248/30, q=79/30$.

Comment: Particular solution  $y_p(x)$ is fixed (without a constant), it is the total solution $y(x)=y_p(x)+y_g(x)$ the needs to satisfy the given conditions. See my edit.

Comment: It made my understanding easy. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: You are welcome!